# How can I tell program to read "n" numbers from file (C++)?

Tags: c++, cin

How can i tell programm to read firstly from the 1st line, to check "n" and then to read as many numbers as "n"?

e.g. if n=5, the program must read 5 numbers from the second line. if n=0, it will read nothing.

can anyone help?

Comment: If this is homework... please tag it accordingly

Comment: you should really, really work on your intendation and re-edit your question.

Comment: You forgot to mention what a and b are supposed to be.

Comment: Please fix your indentation and your spelling.

Comment: a and b are the numbers of empty pages, indexes of empty array

Comment: "guyz". Really? :( And your code is all over the place. Please take more care when writing questions.

Comment: I will. sorry  this time

Comment: explain better or directly quote the homework text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something simple like this would work. Here you are reading a `totalNum` and reading `totalNum` numbers into the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

  int totalNum = 0;
  cin >> totalNum;
  std::vector<int> numArr;
  while( totalNum-- > 0 )
  {
      int num = 0;
      cin >> num;
      cout << "Read " << num << endl;
      numArr.push_back(num);
  }

  cout << "Numbers are ";
  for ( int i = 0; i < numArr.size(); ++i )
      cout << numArr[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```